# Create proxy service to WSO2 ESB from existing external rest web service (C#)

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, esb, wso2-esb

I just want to know if it is possible to create a proxy service to WSO2 ESB from existing external rest web service (C#)? If possible, is there any guidelines or sample on how to do it? I already tried googling but didn't find any, in WSO2 website the is a sample but it creating an API through JAVA and upload (CAR) file to ESB Management Console, I don't want to convert my existing rest web service to JAVA because it will cost so much time and I am not that familiar with JAVA, my existing REST web service is develop using Web api 2.0 (C#).

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, even without any Java knowledge. You'll just have to setup the proxy in your ESB to point to your C# webservice. You can use any webservice as an endpoint for a proxy service, no matter the underlying language of the service. In the end, webservices should be implementation independent. That's what it's all about. Only the provided interfaces matter.

Have a look at this documentation for ESB5: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service

It contains samples to provide a REST webservice through a proxy receiving either REST or SOAP requests.